# How to validate a user that is not approved asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I have a problem with validating a user before he gets approved. Here is the code:

> public void Login(LoginViewModel model)
>           {
>
> ```
>         if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
>         {
>             if (Membership.GetUser(model.UserName).IsApproved)
>             {
>
>                 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.KeepMeLoggedIn);
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 throw new Exception("Your email is not verified yet. Please check your email!");
>             }
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             throw new Exception("Username or Password doesn't match");
>         }
>     }
> ```

The problem is that even when the username and password are good, but the user is not approved yet, it throws the second exception.

I was trying to override the ValidateUser, but I can't call it.

> ```
> public class MyValidation : SqlMembershipProvider
>     {
>         public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
>         {
>             MembershipUser user = GetUser(username, false);
>             if (!user.IsApproved)
>             {
>                 return true;
>             }
>
>             return base.ValidateUser(username, password);
>
>         }
>     }
> ```

Any suggestions?

edited: Controller Code

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        AccountService service = new AccountService();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                service.Login(model);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                TempData["errorMessage"] = e.Message;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

I mention that Login is a partial view

Comment: I don't think that: throw new Exception("Your email is not verified yet. Please check your email!"); is an exceptional condition.

Comment: all this kind of exceptions are temp data in my controler and I show an error message. If you have another suggestion ....

Answer (score 0):

> I was trying to override the ValidateUser, but I can't call it.

When you are calling the `Membership.ValidateUser` this will look for the membership provider registered in your web.config. So if you have configured your custom provider then it will invoke your custom ValidateUser method:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="MyProvider" type="MvcApplication1.MyValidation, MvcApplication1" />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

Also you shouldn't be throwing exceptions in those cases because those are not exceptional cases. Use exception to handle only exceptional cases. You should be adding errors to the ModelState. Also controller actions should return `ActionResults` not `void`. Please look at the `LogOn` action of the `AccountController` that is created by default for you when you start a new MVC application.

Comment: that is not the controller. that is an aditional method in a service class that I call in the controller

Comment: Then this method should return true or false or if you need to handle other cases some enum type and then add errors to the ModelState inside the controller. In this case my remark about the ActionResult return type doesn't hold of course.